# Added sugar instead of syrup to sorbet mixture

Tags: sorbet

I made a sorbet at work and I was in such a rush. I'm still new to the making sorbet (it legit is one of the simplest things ever), but I had the biggest bonehead moment ever and put sugar in it instead of sugar syrup. Just so you know our recipe is:

700ml sugar syrup 
700ml feijoa juice 
100ml of feijoa vodka

But I did the great thing of putting straight sugar in the mix. Do you have any suggestions own how to resolve it or make it smooth or anything?

Everything is added into one container and now it sits in the freezer (unturned) waiting for some genius to give me the answer I need :)

Comment: Can you [edit] and reword your question to make it a bit clearer? What exactly is your question? And please write a more descriptive title

Comment: So.... did you add 700 ml of sugar?  The problem would be that 700 ml of sugar syrup would have less sugar than that.

Comment: Also, what is the condition of the substance right now? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is the amount of sugar, and to adjust for that the specifics of your sugar syrup would matter (how much water to how much sugar, and is that by weight or volume?)

From there, you could add enough additional juice, vodka and water to regain the proportions, and then it's a problem of dissolving the sugar (which is not being helped by being kept in the freezer while you figure out what to do.)

Running it in a blender or putting it in a mixer with a whisk are typical ways to deal with the dissolving problem, as is warming it up, though you may not want to simmer it as that will affect the vodka and possibly the flavor.

The simplest resolution might be to admit the error and ask your boss what they would like you to do - screw-ups happen, and it might be better to toss the ingredients (or pay for them and take them home to try your salvage operation on) than to try and save them and end up serving inferior product. Generally the cost of ingredients is a small fraction of the price of the product served, and serving a bad batch might have a long-lasting negative impact on anyone who got that batch.